# Changing format of dates in ArcGIS 10.2 table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, date

I am working with a table in ArcGIS 10.2 with over 500 entries containing dates. I am looking for a fast solution to transform the format of dates, from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy.

So if a date is 10/08/1999, I need it to be 08/10/1999.

Is there any way to do this, maybe using the field calculator?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to clarify the format of the data table source and the datatype of the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field is a date field, all you have to do is change the date and time formats in your regional settings. Choose a locale that displays months before days, like e.g. `English (United States)`. You can also customize the date format on the additional settings, if you want to keep your current locale.

An alternative is using the [Convert Time Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm) tool. It will convert your date field to a numeric/text field and vice versa, and you will be able to specify a date format conversion at the same time.

I also advise you to take a look at the page [Best practices for storing temporal data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/time/best-practices-for-storing-temporal-data.htm), an interesting read.